# Proof About Linearly Independent Columns of Products of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification

I have a question and provided a solution but I am not sure about my solution. Thus, any inputs and suggestions are welcome.

Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n},$ with $m\ge n,$ and
$$ A = BC $$
where $ B \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ has linearly independent columns and $C \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}.$ Show $A$ has linearly independent columns if and only if $C$ is nonsingular.

\begin{align*}
A \text{ has linearly independent columns } & \Leftrightarrow B  C \text{ has linearly independent columns }\\
& \Leftrightarrow (B C) x = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution.}\\
& \Leftrightarrow B ( C  x) = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution.}\\
& \Leftrightarrow B  y  = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution.}\\
& \Leftrightarrow C x  = 0 \text{ has only the trivial solution.}\\
& \Leftrightarrow  C  \text{ is nonsingular.}
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Comment: Since $B\bar{C}$ is $m \times n$ (rectangular), stating "$B\bar{C}$ is nonsingular" is meaningless.

Comment: The notations of the original problem are quite messy. If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}, B \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$ and $C \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$, then the zero matrix in the rightmost block matrix shouldn't be there, otherwise the dimensions are not compatible. In other words, you could directly state $A = BC$ by removing $0$.

Comment: You already said $B$ is $m \times n$, which makes the rows of $\begin{pmatrix} C \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ to be $n$. In addition, you said $C$ is $n \times n$. So there is no space for the $0$! If $0$ was $(m - n) \times n$, then $\begin{pmatrix} C \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ would have $n + m - n = m$ rows. Therefore, you either made a typo on the dimension of $B$ or $0$ in the block matrix shouldn't exist.

Comment: I think you are right. The $0$ shouldn't be there. What about if we consider $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times p}, \ p\geq n$ which one will be more appropriate in your opinion?

Comment: Now the question is correct (except that you could have dropped the brackets around any matrix). Then you don't have to introduce the notation $\bar{C}$, which is simply $A = BC$. And again, it's meaningless to call a rectangular matrix $A$ "nonsingular".

Comment: I've updated it. Could you check for me?